# Spring Boot JPA StackOverflowError

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, associations

I am new at spring boot JPA. I am trying the examples described here:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany#Example_of_a_OneToMany_relationship_database

so I have defined the two entities:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
  @Id
  @Column(name="EMP_ID")
  private long id;
  ...
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="owner")
  private List<Phone> phones;
  ...
}
```

and:

```
@Entity
public class Phone {
  @Id
  private long id;
  ...
  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="OWNER_ID")
  private Employee owner;
  ...
}
```

(an employee can have more than one phone number, work, home, etc.). The problem is that, when I try to list the Employee instances with my entityManager:

```
public List<Employee> getAll() 
{
    return entityManager.createQuery("from Employee").getResultList();
}
```

I got a spring StackOverflowError. Actually I am trying to refer Employee, which includes a list of Phone(s), but a Phone refers an Employee back so is it not a recursion? I feel as I am missing something about bi-directional associations (uni-directional associations worked fine) .. how can I have an entity A which refer B, being B referring A, and got a JSON response correctly from spring? Can someone point me in the right direction?

I found this workaround:

[Infinite Recursion with Jackson JSON and Hibernate JPA issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325387/infinite-recursion-with-jackson-json-and-hibernate-jpa-issue)

using @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference I can tell Jackson not to serialize one side on my association and it works! But the final result is a unidirectional association (I can see the list of phones on the employee entity, but not the employee on every phone instance). So what is the purpose of bi-directional association if I have to cut one side of them in order to have my code working? Very confused :)

Comment: I believe Hibernate can manage this bi-directional association pretty well. It's only when Jackson tries to build the JSON from your object structure, it goes into recursion.

Comment: So the point is that bi-directional associations are OK from the hibernate point of view, but of course I cannot retrieve such as object through jackson (reasonable)

Comment: clearly the stack trace would tell people where the recursion is in method calls ... JPA or JSON. But we cant see it

Comment: You should be able to tell from the stacktrace

Comment: The comment from Uday is correct:

I believe Hibernate can manage this bi-directional association pretty well. It's only when Jackson tries to build the JSON from your object structure, it goes into recursion. @UdayFokane please add this as the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe Hibernate can manage this bi-directional association pretty well. It's only when Jackson tries to build the JSON from your object structure, it goes into recursion.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `@Data` in your entity then try to override the `toString` method.

I have faced the same issue but after overriding the `toString` method it got resolved.
May be `toString` creates circular dependency while converting.